# How to fix For Loop and If condition NOT working in Bash Script

Tags: bash, loops

I have that For Loop with If condition but it's Not working correctly.
It supposes to check each index value if < 255 display Valid else Not Valid.
The third and Forth are not correct.

How to fix that issue?

```
listNumber=(25 255 34 55)
listLength=${#listNumber[@]}
isValid=0

for ((index=0; index<$listLength; index++)); do
    itemNumber="$((index+1))"
    
    if [[ ${listNumber[$index]} < 255 ]]; then
        echo -e "Item $itemNumber : ${listNumber[$index]} is Valid. \n"
        isValid=1
    else
        echo -e "Item $itemNumber : ${listNumber[$index]} is NOT Valid. \n"
    fi
done

Result:
Item 1 : 25 is Valid. 

Item 2 : 255 is NOT Valid. 

Item 3 : 34 is NOT Valid. 

Item 4 : 55 is NOT Valid.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `<` when used inside `[[...]]` will use string comparison:

> When used with [[, the ‘<’ and ‘>’ operators sort lexicographically using the current locale.

Source: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-commands_002c-conditional

You either use the appropriate arithmetic comparison operator, which is `-lt` in this case:

```sh
if [[ ${listNumber[$index]} -lt 255 ]]; then
fi
```

Or use an arithmentic context for the condition, which is denoted using double parentheses (similar to how you've written the `for` loop):

```sh
if (( ${listNumber[$index]} < 255 )); then
fi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciate your help :)

Comment: @BruceQ. happy to help :)